# Why for Spinoza is the essence of the mind eternal?

Tags: spinoza, essence, necessity

[image]

Quoted in The Oxford Handbook of Spinoza, 302.

I'm confused as to why, if we express the essence of the body under the aspect of eternity -- which for the purposes of the question I take to mean its eternal existence including after death -- there is an essence of the mind that must be eternal.

Is the idea that:

1. the essence of the body is the essence of the mind, because mind and body are identical;
2. we have *by necessity* an idea of the essence of the body after death;
3. and anything we have by necessity, necessarily exists, if it is the essence of itself?

If so, then is mind and body identical merely by undergoing identical changes? And why think that an idea of eternal physical life is had necessarily by everyone? And why think that a necessary essence always exists?

---

There seems to be some debate about whether Spionza believed in personal immortality.

[image]

Spinoza
By Michael Della Rocca, p254

There are differences from the traditional religious perspectives, I'm sure. I repeat: "the human mind cannot be absolutely destroyed with the body". There are standard and dissenting views

[image]

Human Freedom After Darwin: A Critical Rationalist View
By John W. N. Watkins

Comment: See [Nadler's book](https://partiallyexaminedlife.com/2014/09/09/nadler-on-immortality-for-maimonides-vs-spinoza/), where we read:"*The essence of the mind is eternal, to be sure, but that’s not what Spinoza’s talking about when he says that we can bring it about that the greater part of our mind is eternal... the ideas by which we have adequate knowledge are eternal, and the more of them we possess, the greater part of our mind is eternal.*" There is no "life after death", our mind just happens to partake in reified platonic abstractions.

Comment: My sense is that you're misreading the quotation. Where do you get life after death? Sub specie aeternitatis is the way the mind grasps the unchanging essence of things by discarding contingent and perspectival aspects. I don't see how the passage quoted has anything to do with life after death.

Comment: yeah it's a matter of debate what he means (i.e. it's not settled, and not really a "misreading") @transitionsynthesis

Comment: I don't know of any serious readers of Spinoza who say that 'sub species aeternitatis' has anything to do with life after death.

Comment: define a "serious reader of spinoza"? do you mean personally? sorry i don't understand what you mean @transitionsynthesis

Comment: I mean you're misunderstanding what 'sub species aeternitatis' means.

Comment: great -- thanks. can you offer a definition and i'll let you know if it's different to mine @transitionsynthesis

Comment: I did in my first comment. Sub specie aeternitatis is the way the mind grasps the unchanging essence of things by discarding contingent and perspectival aspects. It is a mode of truth. It doesn't have anything to do with whether humans have life after death.

Comment: well, i disagree with your point "it doesn't have anything to do..."

Comment: Disagree based on what, exactly? It is not really a "matter of debate", some people just want to attach "life after death" somewhere no matter how much the text does not bear it.

Comment: i could just as well say the same of naturalism

Comment: Yes, we can all say anything about anything. But "the human mind cannot be absolutely destroyed with the body" for the trivial reason that it is filled with "adequate ideas" that are those of eternal God/Nature. This makes one appreciate Peirce's paradoxical formulation that individual man's "*separate existence is manifested only by ignorance and error*". And that part isn't eternal.

Comment: ok well the first sentence was the point of my saying my last comment. wrt to youe second, so God / nature is something separate from man, for Spionza @Conifold i'm not sure what relevance the "paradoxical formulation" is. how am i saying that man exists separately, and what from?

Comment: Spinoza's God/Nature isn't separate from anything. Men do have plenty of "adequate knowledge", including that of God/Nature's "eternal and infinite essence". Your latest questions seem to query Spinoza on existentialist concerns (that he really couldn't care less about), and I am curious what the motivation is.

Comment: no i'm not saying "so what" to his existential concerns. not deliberately at all. are you saying that we have a duty to believe there's no after-life in order to live happily? that's not very kantian @Conifold i could agree we have a duty to say "so what" to its existence

Comment: It is Spinoza who is indifferent to existentialism. I do not follow why you mentioned yourself, duty to believe, Kant, or living happily.

Comment: oh right, i was unaware that spinoza was uncocerned with existential questions @Conifold so i misread your sentence. then why the ethical questions, aren't they existential? i guess my motivation is that i struggle to make sense of ethics without being clear on the nature of 'eternal life'

Comment: do you follow what i i said now @Conifold bleh, no eternal life without "God". who cares.

Comment: Spinoza is famous for renaming things. "Substance", which is a single one, "God" which is Nature, "modes" and "attributes", which have little to do with what is usually so called. It should not be surprising that "ethics" stands for what is closer to metaphysics, and that while the existential, as in what is, is front and center, the *existentialist*, with its modern personal touch, is completely alien to it (in contrast to Descartes's, say). If there is an ethical message from Spinoza it is the Stoic one: run along "adequately" or you will be dragged along just the same.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply! why do you mean by "modern touch" and what's it got to do with what i said @Conifold ? you seem able to drive a wedge between early modern philosophy and a contemporary person's concerns with ethics and eternal life, which i cannot. why? i don't much care for your tone (you've complained about mine), which often seems very over-eager to point out supposed mistakes in what i say, rather than explain what mistakes i've made. that itself seems like self importance -- however much i value your contributions

Comment: i'm just suggesting that the better users of the site take a more pedagogical approach to comments @transitionsynthesis is Rocca a "serious reader" of spinoza?

Comment: I think Conifold tries to express that Spinoza is a philosopher who is positive and doubtless towards eternal, universal truths and that the modern existentialist thinking of doubt and individuality (which opens the door for the broad discussion of individual death) is completely alien to his thinking. Instead, there is only the one eternal substance - god - which implies that "individuals" are a) only modes of God and not substantially individual and b) our minds, which are equally not "unique" or "independent", can only partake in eternity as thinking a "species" of the eternal truths of God

Comment: fwiw, i'm almost certainly too self centred in what i read and ask -- perhaps just because no-one is setting me questions! but that's a mere attitude, and doesn't mean what i say and ask is deficient at all. so thanks @PhilipKlöcking too much individualism today. interesting!

Comment: I think it is important to probe into texts driven by one's own background and interest. But one thing I learnt during my formal education is that one should be careful that a mind full of opaque ideas about what could be read into a text (mine was not and is not any different with regard to that) should always be careful not to get ahead of itself: Philosophy begins not with these ideas, but with careful explorations what the point actually is **exactly** and whether the text really does provide something for it or has merely been a source of inspiration here.

Comment: Spinoza is, perhaps ,the only philosopher who claimed that the human mind participates actively in metaphysical reality and thereby has the agency to entertain apoedictic certainty or 'truth'. In E5p22, he express the nature of that certainty as the connection between the 'idea; in the mind of god and the human mind.

Comment: Look, I don't deny that it can be a matter of debate about whether not Spinoza thinks there is immortality. I took issue with this:"express the essence of the body under the aspect of eternity -- which for the purposes of the question I take to mean its eternal existence including after death". Again, to look upon something sub species aeternatatis is to look upon its abstract, unchanging essence. Something's having an essence of that sort is a separate question from whether or not we have immortal life.

Comment: not sure if you're still here @PhilipKlöcking , but do you know whether the essence of the mind is subject to change, according to spinoza?

Comment: @unidentified A ping will summon me eventually ;) First off, I think speaking of "essence of mind" in Spinoza seems misleading to me. Mind (or, as he frames it, thought) is a mode of expression of the one essence/substance of God **and**, as such, it is necessarily just the way it is. So, if individual minds change, it is due to the one Being expressing itself differently. Consequently, any real change, individuality, or free will, is delusional according to Spinoza. A misconception arising out of distorted ideas won through perception and sophism.